# Extra whitespace below sticky footer in FF and IE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, whitespace, footer

For some reason, I'm getting some extra whitespace (about 1px) under my sticky footer in Firefox and Internet Explorer. It looks fine in Chrome though.

I'm using the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <header><p>Header</p></header>

    <div id="main">
        <p>Content here...</p>
    </div>

    <footer><p>Footer</p></footer>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#main {
    padding: 20px 0 120px 0; /* padding-bottom must be same height as the footer */
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r09f6pc1/3/) (Try resizing the window if the issue isn't visible right away)

I just can't figure out what's causing it. Firebug doesn't show any elements in that whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow:hidden` to the container

also

`bottom:0px` sometimes is interpreted as bottom:1px because of rounding (ceil/floor) issues

that doesn't happen in any browser, but apparently happens on msie